Blenderkit model looks different when added into the scene
I'm trying to add a mountain into my scene from Blenderkit, I can see some zig zag black lines in the mountain, something which is not visible in the thumbnail of the Blenderkit model.


If you push N to open the side panel, under View try setting Clip Start to like .5 and Clip End to 5000 or something. Does that fix it? This can be a problem when your scene has really big meshes, like landscapes/mountains for instance.

Yes, it does, thanks for the information.

The other problem Im facing now, is getting the mountain to appear within the camera. I press 0 on the number pad, and the mountain wont show up, I try zooming in and out, but the mountain is not appearing in my camera. Its a bit confusing. Can you link me to a tutorial which can help me?

The camera so small its hard to control, to get the mountain in view.
https://ibb.co/GTvMHMR

The camera has also clipping settings. They are independent of the viewport's settings. Select the camera in the outliner, then the Object Data Properties tab (green camera icon), and look for the Lens > Clip Start and Clip End values in the first section (Lens). -- If you want to have a larger camera in the viewport you can change the size with the Viewport Display > Size value. But you can also select it in the outliner and focus it with the "numpad period" key.

@blenderbreath This image should help explain what you're doing when you change the near/far clip values. Your mountain is bigger than the values the default clip space has.

Thank you for the explanation.
